# Установка Zabbix Agent на Linux сервер

Tags: zabbix

Хотел поделиться своим опытом установки **Zabbix Agent** (из исходных файлов) на систему Debian
Большое спасибо [Михаилу Григорьеву](https://blog.programs74.ru/how-to-build-zabbix/) за информацию, она очень помогла решить некоторые тупиковые моменты.

Существует [офф.инструкция](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/ru/manual/installation/install#%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2_zabbix) по установке **Zabbix Agen**t из исходных кодов, но в ней описаны общими словами  некоторые моменты установки, которые очень важны.

Для установки нам необходимы два дистрибутива:

- [Zabbix Agent](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zabbix/)
- Библиотека [PCRE](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre.html)

Порядок установки **Zabbix Agent** на **Debian**:

1. Создадим папку и распакуем архив **PCRE**
2. Необходимо выполнить команду:

`./configure --prefix=/usr --docdir=/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.43 --enable-unicode-properties --enable-pcre16 --enable-pcre32 --enable-pcregrep-libz --disable-static && make`

правильность выполнения конфигурирования можно проверить командой:

```
make check
```

=========================================================================
Если в результате всё зелёное, то вам повезло и всё выполнилось корректно. У меня иногда возникали две ошибки компиляции:

- "*No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH*" - 
  я решил её выполнив команду:

  `apt-get install build-essential`
- "*.... because zlib.h was not found*" - я решил её выполнив команду:

  `apt-get install libs-dev`

========================================================================

3. Выполняем установку:

   `make install && mv -v /usr/lib/libpcre.so.* /lib &&
   ln -sfv ../../lib/$(readlink /usr/lib/libpcre.so) /usr/lib/libpcre.so`

установка библиотеки PCRE выполнена

4. Устанавливаем сам Zabbix Agent. Для этого так же создаём папку и распаковываем в неё исходные файлы
5. Выполняем команду:

   `./configure --enable-agent && make install`
6. Нам необходимо создать пользователя и группу **Zabbix** на сервере

   `groupadd zabbix`

   `useradd -g zabbix zabbix`
7. Создаём каталог для хранения логов работы агента

   `mkdir /var/log/zabbix`

   меняем права `chown zabbix:zabbix /var/log/zabbix`
8. Инсталлятор файл конфигурации **zabbix_agentd.conf**, по-умолчанию размещает в `/usr/local/etc/`
   **zabbix_agentd.pid** размещает в `/tmp/`

Собственно установка закончена и командой `zabbix_agentd` мы можем запустить нашего агента.

Это всё хорошо до тех пор, пока у вас не возникнет необходимость перезапустить Агента.
Агент, установленный таким образом, автоматически не прописывается в системе как служба/сервис и его нельзя стандартными командами ОС остановить/запустить/перезагрузить.
Один из способов остановить и запустить заново - это "убить" процесс командой

`killall zabbix_agentd`
Но, как я понимаю, это не самый правильный способ. И вот приходится "ручками" доделывать то, что авторы не сделали (в полном и необходимом объёме).

Авторы написали init скрипы, но почему-то не стали их автоматически копировать в соотвествующие каталоги. В папке, которую мы создали и в которую распаковали **tar** архив ***/home/zabbix(ver....)/misc/init.d/debian/*** есть файл ***zabbix-agent**
Нам его нужно скопировать в /etc/init.d/*zabbix-agent

Далее, спасибо Михаилу Григорьеву за [код](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/CHERTS/84dc9b7eaa36fcc6822c274a399ac35a/raw/a42699bc3717f2d10531a8c9092a7978efa105ec/zabbix-agent.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=Zabbix Agent
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="CONFFILE=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/zabbix-agent
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
PIDFile=/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
KillMode=control-group
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd -c $CONFFILE
ExecStop=/bin/kill -SIGTERM $MAINPID
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

создаём файл **zabbix-agent.service** и помещаем его в `/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-agent.service` с правами "644"

"Убиваем" `killall zabbix-agentd` если у нас был запущен **zabbix-agentd**.

Ну собственно и всё. Теперь мы можем управлять нашим Zabbix Agent через команду ОС

`service zabbix-agent start/stop/restart/status`

Если у кого-то есть какие-нибудь замечания/комментарии/дополнения пожалуйста напишите.

Comment: Есть вопрос: зачем это все собирать из исходников, если для всяких дебианов есть готовый deb пакет?

Comment: Бывает такое, что установить Zabbix надо туда, где нет выхода с Интернет. Изолированные сети. Вот в таких случаях нужно "химичить" с вариантами установки.

Comment: Ну вы же как-то залили на этот изолированный хост исходники агента? Ничто же не мешает залить на него аналогичным образом rpm-ку или deb-пакет. "Химичить", на мой взгляд надо тогда, когда не хватает базовой комплектации программы. Ваша заметка была бы гораздо информативнее, если бы, например, собрали его с поддержкой oracle клиента.